# ng-zorro datepicker components' error in Lazy Loaded feature modules

Tags: angular7, ng-zorro-antd

Ant Design's NG-ZORRO is pretty straightforward if it is imported in the core app.module

My Use Case: 
I want to load ngZorro in a UiLibraryModule (which sets providers of Zorro and re-exports NgZorroAntdModule) and import that into by Feature1Module, and skip it being imported in app.module (for a lighter vendor.js)

If ng-zorro is *not* included in app.module, I get this error when an ng-zorro datepicker component is called: 
`StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DatePipe]: ..... NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!`

If UiLibraryModule is also imported in app.module, everything works fine (but naturally, with a huge vendor.js)

Problem (best guess):
ngZorro works properly only when imported in the core app.module. But this defeats the whole purpose of having it lazy-loaded by Feature1Module.

**Any suggestions on how to load ng-zorro purely from a lazy-loaded module?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a member of the ng-zorro team. :)

Frankly, it's a bug. This is because `DatePicker` uses a service called `DateHelperService`, which depends on `DatePipe`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  useFactory: DATE_HELPER_SERVICE_FACTORY,
  deps: [Injector, [new Optional(), NZ_DATE_CONFIG], DatePipe]
})
```

For now, you can provide `DatePipe` in `AppModule`. We would fix that in the next version. Thank you for finding this bug.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a ton for the quick and apt reply. 
I tried that, but I get `"InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "zh-cn".' for pipe 'DatePipe'"` whenever the lazy loaded module loads and the datepicker appears.

Comment: PS: I am setting the providers and i18n for ngZorro in the UiLibraryModule

Comment: When I follow this, zorro defaultsto "zn-cn" locale. Could you tell me how to set the locale to en for lazy loaded module for this specific use case ?

Comment: It is related to the hierarchy of injectors. You can try to move all i18n things to the app module.

Comment: BTW, we fixed the problem in a recent PR. You can also wait for it.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue with the latest release too (ng-zorro-antd@7.5.0)

I am importing/exporting NgZorroAntdModule from a UiLibraryModule which has providers:[] and also a forRoot config to set the i18n providers for Zorro. However, none of those methods work as the date components default to `"zh-cn"` and you get the error `Missing locale data for the locale "zh-cn"`!

Here is how I solved it right now:

In *your lazy loaded module's entry/first-loaded/common/shell component*, add the following:

```
    import { en_US, NzI18nService } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
    ..
    constructor(private i18n: NzI18nService) {
    }
    ....
    ngOnInit() {
         this.i18n.setLocale(en_US);
    }
```

The downside is you might have to repeat this for multiple feature modules.

**EDIT:**
`[DatePipe] error` is sorted in 7.5.0+ btw. The solution above is for i18n error (when a locale is set for ngZorro i18n via a Shared/Lazy-Loaded module, it still defaults to "zh-CN"). This is a workaround for that.

Comment: this fixed it for me, i was only having this problem in my unit tests, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem in unit tests, just do this:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common'; import zh from '@angular/common/locales/zh';
```

and beforeEach:

```
registerLocaleData(zh);
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 7.3.0, you can import a component's module and style files to use that component. For example, if you only want to use the `Button` component, you can import `NzButtonModule` instead of `NgZorroAntdModule`, and `Button`'s style file instead of `ng-zorro-antd.css`.

In your modules:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NzButtonModule
  ]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

In style.css:

```css
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/style/index.min.css"; /* Import basic styles */
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/button/style/index.min.css"; /* Import styles of the component */
```

If you want to import several components, it is recommended to use less instead of CSS. In styles.less:

```css
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/style/entry.less"; /* Import basic styles */
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/button/style/entry.less"; /* Import styles of the component */
```

> Importing CSS files of several components may result in code redundancy because style files of components have dependency relationships like TypeScript files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My use case is a bit different actually. I need the whole module, however, it gives errors (no provider for datePipe) when loaded by a lazy-loaded module and any date component is used.

Comment: `DatePipe` is one of `@angular/common` pipe class, and zorro use it to handle date formats. maybe you should import `DatePipe`?

Comment: Absolutely. But the error is generated by zorro. I can import DatePipe to my UiLibraryModule, but the error is still generated by zorro's date component.